# How to bind datepicker to ngmodel

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I have setup date picker within my form according to this:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```html
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon"  >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How do I add this to the `ngModel`?

Binding it the same way as I do for other inputs like text, radio has no effect at all.

```html
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext" ngModel> <-- works
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="mydate" ngModel> <-- doesnt work
    <div class="input-group-addon"  >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I want to bind it exactly the same way as I do it for other inputs.
The `component.ts` is aware of the new field of `mydate` but it remains empty.

Comment: Here's an article about it.. https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-use-bootstrap-datepicker-in-angularexample.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface for the date picker logic.

That would take quite a lot of time and at the end of the day, you have a good chance to do a clone of [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) or [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/). You might consider using one of those right away. Those two are already well polished by the community.